# Construct a Map using object reference as key using Streams API and Collectors.toMap()

Tags: java, lambda, collections, java-8, java-stream

I want to construct a `Map<Item, List<String>>`, i.e. using the `Item` reference as key, with some arbitrary `List<String>` as value. I've attempted the following, but it will show type inference error in IntelliJ (however, it will still *compile*);

```
List<Item> items = getItems(...);
Map<Item, List<String>> itemMap = items.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(i->i, new ArrayList<>()));
```

I then created a workaround through a helper method in `Item`, `get()`, which just returns its own instance;

```
public Item get(){ return this; }
```

Then tried the same approach, using the `get()` method to access the reference:

```
List<Item> items = getItems(...);
Map<Item, List<String>> itemMap = items.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(Item::get, new ArrayList<>()));
```

Now it will at least compile, but it *feels wrong*.

How would one actually go around solving this in a proper manner?

Edit: Question is now radically different from what was originally posted, reflected by the comments received.

Comment: Your second approach does *not* compile, for the very same reason the first one doesn’t. Besides both are missing a `)`, they are using a string constant where a `Supplier` is expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The proper way of achieving it was to include a type argument like so;

```
List<Item> items = getItems(...);
Map<Item, List<String>> itemMap = items.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(Function.<Item>identity(), v -> new ArrayList<>()));
```

Alternatively;

```
List<Item> items = getItems(...);
Map<Item, List<String>> itemMap = items.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(v -> v, v -> new ArrayList<String>()));
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71789/discussion-on-answer-by-habitats-construct-a-map-using-object-reference-as-key-u).

Answer (score 3):

In your first attempt, it should be :

```
List<Item> items = getItems(...);
Map<Item, String> itemMap = items.stream()
                                 .collect(Collectors.toMap(i->i, 
                                                           i->"some string"));
```

You were missing a `)` and the parameter name for the lambda expression of the value.

Changing the value of the Map to a List doesn't make much difference :

```
List<Item> items = getItems(...);
Map<Item, List<String>> itemMap = items.stream()
                                       .collect(Collectors.toMap(i->i, 
                                                                 i->new ArrayList<>()));
```

Comment: That's not it, see my answer.

Comment: @Eran: I’m *sure* that his answer doesn’t. Takes only 2 seconds to prove. I voted for closing the question; the OP doesn’t seem to be really interested in solving a problem…

Comment: @Holger Yes, I tried the OP's answer code (or at least similar code with String instead of Item), and got the same error as in the original code of the question.

Comment: @Holder: Why the condescending tone? I'm definitely trying to solve my problem. However I tried to simplify my initial dummy code to make it easier to understand, but I believe I simplified away my actual problem as well, which is here: http://i.imgur.com/GS8qjIp.png

Comment: I have updated the question to more precisely match my problem.

Comment: @habitats I would guess the condescending tone came about when you flat-out asserted "That's not it, see my answer" where this is a *correct* answer and yours doesn't even compile (at least it didn't at the time of your said comment).

Comment: @Marko Topolnik: My code wouldn't compile because of a typo, not because it's not the correct answer. This answer, however, will not compile either way.

Comment: I tried this code and it definitely does compile. Your code didn't work due to a) a typo, b) a fundamental type error.

Comment: Unbelievably, just statically importing `toMap` produces an inference error in IntelliJ, not reproduced by `javac`! Now I'm puzzled, I was convinced IntelliJ would be in line with `javac` results.